# Make browser and server use the eNULL SSL/TLS cipher

Tags: browser, encryption, webserver, ssl, debug

Is it possible to make a browser and a web server use SSL/TLS (https) with eNULL cipher for debugging purposes in a development environment (e.g. wireshark capture without setting up SSL stream decryption)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My research shows the following so far:

Mozilla Firefox: support for low/weak/null cipher suites has been removed ([see mozilla bug 799007](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=799007)).

Chromium/Chrome: [the first comment from mozilla bug 799007](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=799007#c0) also states lack of support either.

Internet Explorer: supports some of them but are off by default; the interesting cipher suites for my use-case and listed at [(MSDN) Cipher Suites in Schannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA`, `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5`, and possibly `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256`.
It seems that you can enable/disable and prioritize the ciphers following the instructions at [(MSDN) Cryptography API: Next Generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), starting with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista.